# How to add 50+ subcomponents at once without freeze Dynamics 365 CE?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Adding more than 40 subcomponents at once will freeze #Dynamics365 UI forever. Any tools can allow me to do so more efficiently? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I found so that is to use PowerShell. Apparently, you can turn Excel spreadsheet rows to code. Thanks @ScottDurow. http://develop1.net/public/post/2018/12/01/adding-components-to-cds-solutions-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about adding components to a solution, you may want to look into the [XrmToolbox's](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) [Solution Component Mover](https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox/wiki/Solution-Components-Mover) tool.

Comment: No, I am talking about sub-components not components. I know the component mover tool. Thanks anyway :-).